# Validar una placa de vehículo en Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, validación

Necesito validar una placa de vehículo.

- Debe aceptar solo letras y números.
- La placa **tiene** que ser de 6 caracteres.
- El primero **tiene** que ser una **R** o **S**. Los otros 5 **tiene** que ser **alfabéticos**.

Comment: Y que has hecho hasta ahora para lograrlo?

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte necesitas aportar el código que has estado trabajando hasta ahora. En [so] no se hacen los deberes de clase de otros. Puedes echarle un vistazo a [ask] y a como redactar un [mcve], así podremos ayudarte más fácilmente.

Answer (score 3):

Usa expresiones regulares para validar!! Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como usarlas, solo lo escencial o como idea, al final te dejo una lista links que te pueden servir.

```js
$('body').on('keyup', '#placa', function(){
  var valorPlaca = this.value;
  var digitos = valorPlaca.length;

  // Aqui esta el patron(expresion regular) a buscar en el input
  patronPlaca = /^(R|S)+[A-Z0-9]{5}$/;
  
  if( patronPlaca.test(valorPlaca) )
  {
    $('#mensaje').text('Yeah!! si es correcto');
  }
  else
  {
    $('#mensaje').text('Ups!! no es correcto');
  }
})
```

```css
input{
  padding: 0.5em;
}
#mensaje{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
 <small>Numero de placa</small>
 <br>
 <input id="placa" type="text">
   </label>
   <br><br>
   <span id="mensaje"></span>
```

LINKS:

[Cheat sheet Expression regular](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-cGnpZNlMx-4/TiVfn7wujbI/AAAAAAAAABU/Nb1dgh_XR58/s1600/RegularExpressionCheatSheet.JPG)

[Testeador de patrones](http://regexr.com/)

[HTML5 con patrones en inputs](http://www.html5pattern.com/)

Busca un curso sobre expresiones regulares con Javascript, son muy utiles.

Comment: El evento `keyup`, podría no dispararse con algún cambio de texto, por ejemplo pegando el texto copiado. Convendría usar el evento `input`-

Comment: Asi es Mariano, puede usarse diferentes eventos, dependiendo la necesida, solamente puse un ejemplo de como podria hacerse, para el usuario seria un punto de partida, saludos!!