# Función en JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript

Evaluar una cadena de texto en un `<input type="text">`, los primeros 3 dígitos solo letras, y los siguientes 3 dígitos solo números.

Comment: Falta información concreta y lo que has intentado para poder orientarte colega!

Comment: Tienes algo? Algún tipo de código que tengas implementado en que nos podamos basar?
Me parece una pregunta sin investigación, y podrías empezar por  [expresiones regulares](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Expresiones_regulares_en_javascript)

Comment: Es evaluar placas de vehículos: XYT589. Entonces al guardar o registrar la placa en la base de datos, se evalué en el button, que los primeros 3 caracteres son en letras, y los siguientes 3 son solo en números. Aunque seria mejor que al momento de escribir, solo permita los primeros 3 caracteres en letras y los siguientes 3 en números.

Comment: Carlos: dale a [edit] y añade todos estos detalles en la pregunta! En comentarios es complicado leer

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validarString (cadenaAnalizar) {
   for (var i = 0; i< cadenaAnalizar.length; i++) {
         var caracter = cadenaAnalizar.charAt(i);
        if(caracter[0].isNaN(); && caracter[1].isNaN(); && caracter[2].isNaN();){
         alert('los primeros tres son numeros'):
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jeje pero como la corro, la función en un button (onclick="validarString()" o en el input (onkeypress="validarString()")???

Comment: investiga un poco sobre expresiones regulares, te ayudara mas en esto!

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45666/validar-una-placa-de-veh%C3%ADculo-en-javascript

Comment: Por eso es importante no responder preguntas que no muestran un avance y que se presta a dudas

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar la propiedad pattern que presenta HTML5 para sus elementos input. Este atributo provee una expresión que debe cumplir el campo.

Este atributo no previene de campos no informados, así que utilizaremos required si el campo es un valor obligatorio.

> **HTML5** No soportado en navegadores inferiores a ie9 o safari10

Por otro lado podrias realizar el mismo funcionamiento con **jquery o puro JavaScript**.

Te dejo dos ejemplos:

**HTML5**

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como implementarlo para matriculas y añadir algo de estilo CSS.

```js
document.getElementById('ejemplo').addEventListener('submit',function(evt){

  // Console log
  console.log("Formulario OK.");

  // Previene envio, solo ejemplo
  evt.preventDefault();
  return false;

});
```

```css
input:invalid {
    border-color: red;
}
input,
input:valid {
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<form id="ejemplo" action="/enviar.php">
  Matricula:
  <input type="text" name="matricula" pattern="[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}" title="AAA000" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```js
$('#ejemplo').on('submit',function(evt){

  // Control de envio, simulando propiedad REQUIRED
  $(this).find('input[data-required]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).data('required') && !$(this).val()) {
      alert("Debes cumplimentar: " + $(this).attr('name'));
    }
  });

  // Console log
  console.log("Formulario OK.");

  // Previene envio, solo ejemplo
  evt.preventDefault();
  return false;

});

// Actualización de valor en tiempo real
$('input[data-pattern]').on('keyup',function(){
  var regex = new RegExp($(this).attr('data-pattern'));
  if ( regex.test( $(this).val() ) ) $(this).addClass('valid');
  else $(this).addClass('invalid');
});
```

```css
input.invalid, input[data-required] {
    border-color: red;
}
input,
input.valid {
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="ejemplo" action="/enviar.php">
  Matricula:
  <input type="text" name="matricula" data-pattern="[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}" title="AAA000" data-required="true">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```